# directive needs to modify table after ng-repeat renders rows

Tags: angularjs

I have an table directive, fixed-first-column, with a link function that modifies table row contents. The directive works when applied static html tables.

When table rows are rendered with ng-repeat however, they do not get modified. For example:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" fixed-first-column>
        <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th class="label-text">Performance</th>
            <th ng-repeat="t in steps">Rnd {{t}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-if="metadata[key].show" ng-repeat="key in keys">
            <td class="label-text">{{outcomes[key].label}}</td>
            <td ng-repeat="r in outcomes[key].results">
                <span>{{r.result}}</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I ensure my directive is not applied to the table until after ng-repeat has rendered the table rows?

Comment: If your ngRepeat is on the same element as the directive it is fairly simple to catch the last item in the repeater by calling `scope.$last` in your directive. If not, [here is a little fiddle to play around with.](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ju7t30y9/2/)

Comment: Updated the question to include an example use case. The table directive needs to run after both ng-repeat directives.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a 0 length $timeout. It does cause the table directive code to execute after after both ng-repeat directives

Comment: I used the `$timeout` just to simulate a delayed data response and show that my `repeatEnd` directive was working. I wouldn't use `$timeout` in your code since you have no control over how long the data retrieval takes in ajax calls (for example). I modified my directive to meet more of what I think you're looking for in my answer below.

Comment: The table data is all in the browser when the table is rendered, so I'm not concerned about data retrieval time. I also considered adding a controller for the directive along with a two repeat finished directives -- one for the table header and another for the table body. Your answer gives a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so you have a directive that is wrapping (2) two or more `ngRepeat` items.

Communicating up the chain can be difficult, since each `ngRepeat` has it's own scope, and their parent is the controller scope. Your `fixed-first-column` directive could have it's own scope, but that depends on how you wrote your directive.

So, one option you could do is have a `repeatEnd` directive that captures the end of the repeater and `$emit`'s it.

```
app.directive('repeatEnd', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // Use `scope.$parent.$last` if you want this directive to have an isolated scope
            if (scope.$last) {
                scope.$emit('repeat-ended', element);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your `fixed-first-column` directive you could capture the `$emit` using `$on`

```
app.directive('fixedFirstColumn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('repeat-ended', function (obj, element) {
                console.log("obj", obj);
                console.log("element", element);
                // Your other code here
            });
        }
    };
});
```

<kbd>[Here is a quick fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ju7t30y9/3/)</kbd>

I am passing the element in the `$emit` since you have multiple repeaters so you know which one ended in the `$on` method.